# Chaining active record queries together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search form which contains parameters such as city,building_type,min_price,max_price.

What is the best way to chain all those queries together. If the user doesn't set a parameter, I want it to just return all records.

Something like

```
city=params[:city] || "all"
building_type=params[:building_type] || "all"
min_price=params[:min_price] || "all"

@results= Property.where(city: city,building_type: building_type,min_price: min_price)
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Seeing that there is no "all" keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain active record queries by assigning the results of all the queries you want to do in a single variable

```
properties = Property.all
properties = properties.where(city: params[:city]) if params[:city].present?
properties = properties.where(building_type: params[:building_type]) if params[:building_type].present?
```

Moreover, if the parameter keys are the same as the columns in your database, you can just place all of them in an array and loop through it like

```
properties = Property.all

%i[city building_type min_price].each do |column_name|
  next if params[column_name].blank?
  properties = properties.where(column_name => params[column_name])
end
```

**NOTE**

The first line, `properties = Property.all` assumes that it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which is the default in Rails 4 (not sure).  If you are using Rails 3, just use `Property`.